# Are Xcode breakpoints enabled in "Archive" builds?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I've been testing with breakpoints on (Zombie, malloc_error_break, All Obj-C Exceptions, All Exceptions).  I forgot to turn them off when I made my release/distribution build for the iOS App Store.  Is that an issue? (Xcode 5, iOS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breakpoints are "settings" of the debugger and aren't compiled, so they're not part of the build product. The executable may only contain debug symbols when you archive with debug settings (but default is release).